# SQLite 1.0.82.0 (latest) in Visual Studio 2012 not showing in Designer Data Source

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012, datasource, designer

I am using the latest version, 1.0.82.0 (sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.82.0.exe), and am using the released version of Visual Studio 2012 with all the latest everything.

I do not see the SQLite in the Designer Data Source in Source Explorer (new Connections).

The download on SQLite states, "This setup package is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2010".  I presume the "Visual Studio 2010" part is why I do not see the designer in VS2012, which is what I have.

How can I get the designer to work with VS2012?

When will the System.Data.SQLite.org team come out with a version that works with VS 2012?

(I did see a couple of posts back in July which talked about 1.0.66 and 1.0.73, but that was then and 1.0.82 includes the designers just for VS 2010 apparently.  I see other file names with "-2008" presumably for Visual Studio 2008.  That means that a Visual Studio 2012 will probably come, but in the mean time, I am curious about a manual registry hack or something like that.)

Comment: I have two development machines.  One has Visual Studio 2012 Professional and the other Visual Studio 2012 Premium.  According to documentation, designer support is for Professional and above and not supported on the Express version.

Comment: I got it fixed for me please check my edited answer or it works for you now.

Answer (score 9):

In order to get designer support for SQLite in Visual Studio, you have to download a very specific version of System.Data.SQLite.  The [downloads page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) has an astonishing **56** different possibilities, so it's easy to get the wrong one.

Look for the big bold text that says this:

> **This setup package is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2012.**

But it's still easy to miss among the zillions of downloads.  If you need to, use Control-F to find the "Visual Studio 2012" text.

**Don't download the 64-bit version, even if you're on a 64-bit machine**.  You need the 32-bit version with the text above to get designer support.

Comment: This doesn't work. I downloaded the 32-bit version that said it was the only one that would install design time components for VS 2012. I made sure to check the options to install those components. Tried TWICE to shut down VS, do the install, and start VS back up. No provider for SQLite appears in the list, and I can't get my edmx model to connect or map to my SQLite database. Any other potential reasons/fixes? (already made sure the correct NuGet versions were installed: EF 6.1.1 and SQLite 1.0.94)

Comment: @FireWingLead, are you definitely using VS 2012, and not VS 2013?  It has a different package intended for VS 2013.

Comment: Yes, very definitely using VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

**NEW EDIT NOW I GOT IT WORKING!**

Goto Visual Studio, Manage Nuget, search for online packages, search "SQLite", install System.Data.SQLite, and boom, you can use designer and evrything is working again.

Comment: I just installed 1.0.84.0, still no design-time components out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

After some search I found my answer, 1.0.83, which will come out in November XX, 2012.

Visual Studio 2012 aside from the v10 to v11 registry hive difference also has what the team calls a "redesigned designer support".

Here is the link to the information.

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

1.0.83.0 - November XX, 2012 (release scheduled) 
•Updated to SQLite 3.7.15.
•Add Visual Studio 2012 support to all the applicable solution/project files, their associated supporting files, and the test suite.
•Add Visual Studio 2012 support to the redesigned designer support installer.

and other changes.

I could not find any interim solution on the web, sadly.  The lack of a fix affects report based projects with DevExpress and projects that use the explorer.