# System.Data.SQLite Visual Studio 2012 .NET 4.5 Won't Show in Data Source

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2012, system.data.sqlite

I'm developing on a Winodws 7 x86 machine in Visual Studio 2012 using .NET 4.5. I installed the x86/x64 System.Data.SQLite official Nuget package for my project. But I still don't see it as an option in the Data Source\Data Provider selections in the "Choose data source" dialog. I saw this answer here and it looks like this is all I should have to do ([SQLite 1.0.82.0 (latest) in Visual Studio 2012 not showing in Designer Data Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809929/sqlite-1-0-82-0-latest-in-visual-studio-2012-not-showing-in-designer-data-sour)). Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having a similar problem on Windows 7 x64.  Frustrating since it works on my work PC, but not my home PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This package worked for me.](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.84.0/sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0.exe)

Apparently

> "This setup package is *capable* of installing the design-time
>   components for Visual Studio 2012."

means

> "This setup package is *required for* installing the design-time
>   components for Visual Studio 2012."

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on. I ended up re-installing the setup package and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add this as a followup because I was having issues seeing the designer in VS2012 as well and it may help others in the future.

After multiple attempts at installing the designer and not seeing it show up, I ran 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /setup

This will force VS to rebuild its registry based on all of the installed packages.  This will take a couple of minutes.  Afterwards, I was able to start up VS 2012 and see the entry.

I am curious whether the installer executes this command at all or if it just triggers it but does not wait for it to finish.  At which point the end user opens VS 2012 before the command has time to finish.