# Visual Studio 2012 SQLite Install Not Appearing

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, system.data.sqlite

I have downloaded and installed sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.88.0.exe, but despite following various instructions have not been able to see it in any way from within Visual Studio 2012.  From what I understand, it is only the x86 install package shown above that will install the visualizer into VS2012.  I have opened the Choose Data Source dialog from the Server Explorer, and do not see the SQLite Database File option shown.  Additionally, I have tried adding SQLite to my project and installing via the NuGet system, which appeared to install correctly, however I still see nothing anywhere.  I have read various tutorials and it seems I am following all the instruction correctly, except I do not see SQLite listed anywhere in any lists of Data sources.  I have tried doing this with a new project, and after restarting my machine, but same result, nothing.  What am I doing wrong, or what can I reset or try differently?  Some obvious step I am missing that everyone assumes?  Thanks.

Comment: This might help you (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809929/sqlite-1-0-82-0-latest-in-visual-studio-2012-not-showing-in-designer-data-sour)

Comment: Thanks, but I had already read that thread, I have made sure to install the correct version already.  Does anyone know of some way to reset VS2012 so it can see these plugins?  That's part of the problem, I don't even know what this is suppose to be doing, is it a plugin, a tool, utility, macro, very confusing.  An ADO I guess.

Comment: I've used it two times and those two times I used directly in code like this: `var db = new SQLiteConnection("myConnection");` To be honest, I never used "Data Source" to connect to my DBs.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing then uninstalling both the downloadable install and the NuGet installed package.  Then installed using NuGet, then installed with the downloadable package.  I doubt that is actually a real solution, other than it snapped something in place that didn't take the first time.

Anyways, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this info](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html), check it out:

**Install the Provider**
In order to connect to SQLite databases, we will need to install an appropriate ADO.NET and Entity Framework provider. Luckily, the provider we're using is available via NuGet.

1. Inside PMC, run Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.x86

We also need to register the provider. Open App.config, and anywhere inside the configuration element, add the following fragment.

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider"
          invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
          description="Data Provider for SQLite"
          type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```