# vs2015 SQLite Data Provider

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2015, provider

**I have see [other's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507904/vs-2015-sqlite-data-provider),and install sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.98.0.exe**

> But the question is server explore can find the sqlite data provider,As shown below

[image]

> But when i create a new Modal can't find the sqlite data provider,as shown below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> [a way can dealwith it from other's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809929/sqlite-1-0-82-0-latest-in-visual-studio-2012-not-showing-in-designer-data-sour/14111527#14111527)
>
> use nuget add System.Data.SQLite to your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, i had to install this package:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.101.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe
Then i was able to see SQLite data source in VS 2015

Comment: Can you use this after install sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe.      [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl4wT.png)